# Change URL when change language on click language switcher

Tags: 7

I  have Four Different languages Chinese,Portguese,Spanish and English.
My Question is Portguese,Spanish and English same url (example.com) and when user change /click on chinese language icon, change the URl(chineseexample.com).How we can done it?